# nexe : The term 'nexe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable

Tags: node.js

We are facing the below problem when we are trying to build an exe via nexe command. This worked well on a development environment which is a Oracle VM, but on the server machine, this is happening. Nexe module is installed and I could see it in node_modules folder. Please let me know what could be missing.

```
PS <C:\Program Files\iisnode\www\tcnx>> nexe PLM_Adaptor.js --build

nexe : The term 'nexe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct 
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ nexe PLM_Adaptor.js --build
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (nexe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Thanks,
Pavan.

Comment: have u found the solution for this problem ? I had exacly got those error.
if found can u share them, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
npm i nexe -g
```

will install the nexe module in a path like this one:

```
C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

it will also store a file named "nexe.cmd" in this folder. This is the file you actually execute when just typing "nexe" on the commandline.
In order to make this work, make sure nexe.cmd exists in the mentioned npm folder (or locate where it is) and make sure that this folde is in the PATH like so:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score -1):

```
npm i nexe -g
```

run this command and issue will be solved...